# Can I get a hover and checked effect with St.Button in GJS?

Tags: gnome-shell, gnome-shell-extensions, gjs

I have a group button with icon. If I can setup a hover effect, for I saw here is some func or attribute like `St.Widget.track-hover` `St.Widget.sync_hover` `St.Widget.set_hover`, maybe minor changes may be made for buttons using css. But those function is complex to understood, if has some example code can do this?

[image]

Other thing is since no `radio_button` in gjs, if I can use `set_checked()` to do some display effect to show the `checked` statu for my buttons?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> answer to `checked` statu and `radio button` part first.

I found a key line `When the value is true, the St.Button will have the checked CSS pseudo-class set.` refer to [https://gjs-docs.gnome.org/st10~1.0_api/st.button](https://gjs-docs.gnome.org/st10%7E1.0_api/st.button). So I search `checked CSS pseudo-class set`, and know this is controled by `:checked` attribute in CSS file.

First write those lines in `stylesheet.css`.

```
:checked {
  margin-left: 25px;
  border: 4px solid #CBCBCB;
}
```

Then within `extension.js`, set `toggle_mode`, then `set_checked` . It works well.

```
butt[i] = new St.Button({ can_focus: true, child: icon, toggle_mode: true });

butt[0].set_checked(true);
```

Then you can toggle a group buttons like this.

```
butt[i].connect('clicked', (self) => {
    butt.forEach((self)=>{ self.checked = false; });
    self.checked = true;
});
```

I think `hover` is the same way to solve.

Comment: The global style should not be used, but the local style should be used like ".cn:checked".

Answer (score 0):

> answer to `hover` part.

First set this. make the `St.Widget` can `track the pointer hover state`.

```
butt[i].set_track_hover(true);
```

Then setup css like this. This style must change a little color or somethig when mouse over the widget.

```
:hover { background: #404040; }
```

Then connect `style-changed` signal and check the `St.Widget.hover` attribute. When you see the name of the signal, you think that CSS must change before this signal can be emitted. *I tested it many times before found this.*

```
butt[i].connect('style-changed', (self) => {
                if(self.hover){
// do here.
```

Comment: The global style should not be used, but the local style should be used like ".cn:hover".